Incremental Hash Using System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm
Is there a way that the .Net System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm interface can be used to incrementally calculate a hash one byte at a time?
My use case is that I have a CRC32 algorithm that implements HashAlgorithm, but would like to call it incrementally as bytes are received on the wire over the SerialPort. The final CRC value will be retrieved when an end-of-stream byte is received.
Init CRC

While (Condition)
  Add Byte to CRC

Get Final CRC


If the send CRC you get in the end has been created with the same way sure no problem.

I am asking how to use the System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm interface to achieve this?

Is a System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm somehow a must? For example the existing CRC32 class allows appending data already. But its not derived from HashAlgorithm and its A CRC32 its not THE CRC32 . CRC32 is more or less just a word describing likewise but mostly incompatible algorithms. Only when you now explicitly what you get from the SerialPort then you might know what to do on your side and only then if that works incrementally.

If I understand correctly, you implement your own HashAlgorithm and want to add ComputeHash(MyIncrementalHashCalculationState state, Byte byte) overload? Without seeing implementation it's kind of hard to help.

@Ralf I have specific CRC32 algorithm I need to support that isn't the .Net supplied one.

@Sinatr this isn't implementation specific. I'm asking if it is possible with the pure System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm interface as I haven't been able to find a way myself. It may not be, but I was hoping someone might know something I don't.

You need to implement the HashCore method, and maybe the TransformBlock method of the ICryptoTransform interface, and probably a few others. Yes, it's possible.
